# How to set [UIColor [variable here]]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I have a .plist file, containing an array with dictionaries where each entry has a key-value-pair "color1:abc" and "color2:xyz". "abc" and "xyz" are always the standard iOS colors like "redColor" or "yellowColor" and so on.

My app has the "activeItem" from the .plist array and I want to set the color1 and color2 to the background of a view, so I tried something like:

`self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor [activeItem color2]];`

(instead of: `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];`)

But that doesn't work... which syntax would be correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `[activeItem color2]` returns a method name (`redColor`, `yellowColor` and so on), you can use `performSelector:`

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([activeItem color2]); 
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor performSelector:selector];
```

Comment: Perfekt. Thanks. Your answer will be marked as solution in about 8 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to implement a method that interprets the string value and returns the corresponding color.

```
UIColor *colorWithName: NSString *name
{
   if ([@"redColor" isEqualToString: name])
      return [UIColor redColor];
   else if (...)
      ...
}
```

Or put the named colors into an NSDictionary called namedColors and then just look them up by name.

Comment: That would not be very dynamic, would it?

Comment: No, but it would be safer. Using selectors means someone could put any UIColor method name there and it would just be called by the app, which sounds like a backdoor to me.

Comment: OK I see your point now, but as I do manage the data, I do not see a  huge risk there.

Comment: OK, that's something you can judge better than I ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Create class category.

create customColor.h file, for example:

```
@interface UIColor (customColor)

+(UIColor*)color1;
+(UIColor*)color2;

@end

@implementation UIColor (customColor)

+(UIColor*)color1
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
}

+(UIColor*)color2
{
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
}

@end
```

Then you can just use:

```
#import customColor.h
...
UIColor *neededColor = [UIColor color1];
```

Comment: I was not searching for a way to define "custom colors" as I just use the default values. I was searching for a way to use these default values from a variable (or as I learned now from a selector).